# How could I access java Runtime.getRuntime() if the project already have a Runtime Class?

Tags: java, runtime, simulator, ambiguity

I have a code running inside Sinalgo Distributed Algorithm simulator. Sinalgo main thread is named Runtime and it needs to be imported inside all projects to run properly. I also use Sinalgo´s Runtime class. So I have:

```
import sinalgo.runtime.Global;
import sinalgo.runtime.Runtime;
```

However, I also need to access java´s Runtime.getRuntime() and I can´t because it is linked as Sinalgo´s runtime.

How could I access java `Runtime.getRuntime()`?

ps.: I tried to do the `import java.lang.Runtime;` but do not works.

Comment: Just use `java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime();` at the point in code you need to make the call.

Comment: Import one of the Runtimes and use a *fully qualified* name for the other

Comment: Thanks user2478398! It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just specify the package name also if you're using the class which has package other than imported just like "user2478398" has mentioned.
java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime()